# How to programmatically change the text in a power app text input box

Tags: powerapps, textinput

For example I have 2 text input boxes (textInputA and textInputB) in a Power Apps app. On clicking a button I want to change the content of textInputB to the content of textInputA. I have read that this is somehow done by creating a variable to hold the current content of textInputA and then putting it into the default property of textInputB. So far all that has done is display the name of the variable in textInputB. Please can someone tell me how I should go about this.
Thank you.

Comment: Post the actual content of the formula bar for your commands. Show in screenshots, so we can see what you've entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to append or replace?

This button does both.

```
Set(varTextA,TextInputA.Text);
Set(varTextC,Concatenate(TextInputC.Text,Char(10),TextInputA.Text))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got the hang of assigning a variable to the default of the inputText then changing the value of the variable to update the content of the text box. Thank you.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. That's how you can say "thank you" around here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have quotations around your variable's name?
If your variable is named VarX and you have "VarX" in the default property, it will treat your variable like a string, not a variable.